# ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.TokenMgrError: Unmatched '}'

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I am trying to store to HDFS using the AvroStorage() method. The code looks like:

```
store 'data' into 'path' using AvroStorage('schema', $SCHEMA)
```

SCHEMA is a variable I get from doing `cat '/path/to/schema/schema.avsc'`
Right now I am getting an error saying:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.TokenMgrError: Unmatched '}'
```

If I change `using AvroStorage('schema', $SCHEMA)` to `using AvroStorage()`, the program works but I want to use that schema. Can someone suggests what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Without looking at $SCHEMA it's hard to tell, but I would try quoting it like  AvroStorage('schema', '$SCHEMA');

Comment: @Koji Adding quotation mark doesn't help. I am sure the schema is valid. Is there any other reason you can think of that can cause this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your $SCHEMA ?  Also, try running with 'pig -dryrun', that would show you the expanded pig script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. In my case, there are some single quotes in the schema comments. Try to put single quote '$SCHEMA', and also try to replace all single quote in the schema. e.g. cat '/path/to/schema/schema.avsc' | sed "s/'/ /g"